# Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying a develop a website for an online store where users can add products to their carts. When a user add the product or removes it, I don't know why the total price is not correct. I'm a beginner in Django. How can I fix this?

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    context = {"cart":cart}
    template = 'shopping_cart/cart.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    except:
        pass 
    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
        messages.success(request, mark_safe("Product added to cart. Go to <a href='cart/'>cart</a>"))
        return redirect('myshop-home')
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)
        messages.success(request, mark_safe("Product removed from cart"))


    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.products.all():
        new_total += float(item.price)

    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()

   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product


class Cart(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart"
```

Comment: What does not correct mean? Querysets aren't guaranteed to be in the same order so I wouldn't try to access a particular cart in the way you are doing.

Comment: So how should I do it?

Comment: With a  unique identifier, ie cart id or link a cart to a user

Comment: Or even more convenient: link a cart to a session (e.g. in a middleware). That way anonymous users can have carts.

Answer (score 1):

You should associate carts with sessions. That way, any user will consistently have their own cart regardless of login state. You could go with a custom middleware for convenience:

```
# middleware.py
def cart_from_request(self, request):       
    try:
        cart_pk = request.session.get('_cart_pk')
        return Cart.objects.get(pk=cart_pk)
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        request.session['_cart_pk'] = cart.pk
        return cart

class CartMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.cart = cart_from_request(request)
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And add it to your middleware stack:

```
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # ...
    'dotted.path.to.middleware.CartMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

And in any view, you can now simply access `request.cart`.
That being said, having the cart maintain its own total is an unnecessary redundancy. Why not make it a property:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum

class Cart(...):
    # ...

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.products.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))['total'] or 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the model for Product, but I'm guessing you have a DecimalField there too.

I think your only problem may be that you're converting to float. Using DecimalField is correct here, and the reason for that is that you want to avoid float, because float is not as exact as you might think.

```
from decimal import Decimal
# ...
    new_total = Decimal()
    for item in cart.products.all():
        new_total += item.price
cart.total = new_total
cart.save()
```

Or, even better, using builtin sum() and iterator (no need to import Decimal here):

```
cart.total = sum(item.price for item in cart.products.all())
cart.save()
```

Alternatively, this is faster by not loading all objects from database:

```
cart.total = sum(cart.products.values_list('price', flat=True))
cart.save()
```